# Angular-Keycloak requesting URL using /3p-cookies/step1.html instead of /token

Tags: angular, token, keycloak, protocols, openid-connect

I'm trying to use keycloak to authenticate the project I'm working but when I run it the url it tries to reach is:
/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html

instead of
/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token (that I can access in the postman and get my token).

```
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"keycloak-angular": "^12.1.0",
"keycloak-js": "^19.0.3",
```

Does anyone can help me to change it? Is that a configuration or hardcoded in the keycloak version?

I'm googling for hours and I can't find a configuration to change the link it attempts to reach.

I followed this tutorial to configure the Angular keycloak https://wkrzywiec.medium.com/step-by-step-guide-how-integrate-keycloak-with-angular-application-d96b05f7dfdd

Comment: This might help... https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/282

Comment: For me downgrading worked. `npm i -s keycloak-js@10.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

```
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"keycloak-angular": "^12.1.0",
"keycloak-js": "^19.0.3",
```

for above verion, refer follwing example, this example program is working well :
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/keycloak-in-angular-application-980260b4b196

```
"@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
"keycloak-angular": "^13.0.0",
"keycloak-js": "^20.0.0",
```

If you are going to use above versions, You need to skip using standalone mode because this can cause the same error.